# javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException 8.5.35 AND above

Tags: tomcat, attributes

The error I am getting is: Cannot find attribute XXX for org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProperties

This being thrown when I call mBeanServer.getAttribute(blah, blah)

From my understanding this was a bug in Tomcat 8.5.35 and fixed with 8.5.36 - although I found that it has been reported in 8.5.40 as well.

I added a number of tomcat installs to my Eclipse to try to narrow this down and this is what I have found:

8.5.30 WORKS

8.5.34 WORKS

8.5.35 ERROR

8.5.37 ERROR

8.5.40 ERROR

8.5.45 ERROR

8.5.51 ERROR

NOTE that I was unable to find 8.5.36 on the tomcat downloads page.

I can't imagine that a bug found in 8.5.35 that was supposedly fixed in 8.5.36 is continuing to exist all the way up to 8.5.51 and beyond.  This code has worked fine previously for years in lesser versions of Tomcat, but has choked from 8.5.35 and above.

What I am trying to determine is if there were another change or parameter that was introduced that might be needed now as a security measure which is blocking the read. For example, when running 8.5.51, I have to add the secretRequired parameter to the Connector in server.xml, otherwise it chokes. This is on an unrelated part, but hopefully you understand what I am meaning about new parameters being introduced.

In troubleshooting, I am seeing the attribute names, object names, etc. but when I go for the value stored in the attribute, it bombs.

Makes me wonder if there are some enhanced measures in place that need to be set after 8.5.34. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of digging, I finally figured out the issue. Please note that the reported 'bug' in 8.5.35 that was fixed in 8.5.36 is apparently not a bug at all. Pure speculation on my part, but the reported issue exists in subsequent TomCat releases and 8.5.36 is no where to be found.

When getting the mBean Set for calling mBeanServer.getAttribute(), there are actually 2 mBean objects being passed - one is the original that works, the other has an extra key - "subtype=SocketProperties". That extra key was what was throwing the error in my code.

Prior to 8.5.35, there was just the single mBean Set that does not include the subtype key.

My code is basically building an array of ObjectInstances that are filtered for "Type=ThreadPool".

For Example, on a default Tomcat install prior to 8.5.35, you get an ObjectName of:

Catalina:type=ThreadPool,name="blah blah blah"

From 8.5.35 onwards you get 2:

Catalina:type=ThreadPool,name="blah blah blah"

Catalina:type=ThreadPool,name="blah blah blah",subType=SocketProperties

It's that second one the triggers the subsequent error of:
"cannot find attribute maxthreads for org.apache.tomcat.util.net.socketproperties"
when it hits the following line of code:

```
mBeanServer.getAttribute(objectName, "maxThreads")
```

By simply excluding objectNames that contained the subtype key from being added to my array, the problem was resolved.

```
filter = "*:type=ThreadPool,*";
objectName = new ObjectName(filter);
Set<ObjectInstance> setOfInstances = mBeanServer.queryMBeans(objectName, null);
for (ObjectInstance objInst : setOfInstances)
{
    if(!objInst.getObjectName().getKeyPropertyListString().contains("subType"))
        ArrayOfObjects.addElement(objInst.getObjectName());
}
```

I'm sure there is a cleaner way of doing this and I'd love to hear it, but I was just happy to finally figure out the cause of my issue and to get around it.

Hopefully this information might help others who encounter the same issue.